# Recommended way(s) to log events in Corda

Tags: corda

We are capturing a new committed state in the vault through vaultTrack method on Corda RPC proxy for using in the logs recording. Although it’s working properly, we thinks it might have cause some overhead for network connection. So, we decided to try using ServiceHub in the CorDapp for capturing the new event instead. Unfortunately, the event keep occurring every time when the flow is called (based on observable concept?). Maybe we did not set up properly?. Based on your experience and expertise, could you

1. Suggest what went wrong; and
2. The corresponding solutions?

More details here:
As we are using the logs of CorDapp for a performance benchmark. Therefore, we are focusing only **new committed state event**. In API endpoint where we had started, we are using VaultTrack in RPC to record each new committed state event as shown in the example below:

[image]

Although the API seems to work properly but we think it might consume RPC connection in the overall performance since the observable is called every time a new state is committed. Please correct us if we're wrong. As such we decided to change to logging the events in the flow instead.

In CorDapp, we are using VaultService in ServiceHub to record each new committed state event in the ‘call function’ of flow initiator as shown in the example below: 
[image]

We found that the logs recording in CorDapp i.e. in the flow (from the serviceHub mentioned above) keep gaining duplicated log every time the flow is called.  From our initial investigation, we found that the problem is "vaultService" keep getting subscribed every time the flow is initiated. Therefore, we switched back to use the API endpoint method.  Please could you advise us the right way to capture the event in CorDapp. To log the event of a newly committed state during our performance testing.

Answer (score 1):

The approach of subscribing to a vault observable within a flow will not work. Once the flow ends, the subscription will not be terminated. Every time you run the flow, an additional subscriber will be added. This will degrade performance (although the RPC overhead is generally quite low as long as the states serialise quickly enough).

You should observe updates to the vault using an RPC client instead. Here is an example:

```
val client = CordaRPCClient(nodeAddress)
val proxy = client.start(rpcUserUsername, rpcUserPassword).proxy

// Track IOUState updates in the vault
val (snapshot, updates) = proxy.vaultTrack(IOUState::class.java)

// Log the existing IOUStates and listen for new ones.
snapshot.states.forEach { logState(it) }
updates.toBlocking().subscribe { update ->
    update.produced.forEach { logState(it) }
}
```

When you call `start` on the `CordaRPCClient`, you will connect to the node's Artemis message queue. This message queue will be used to stream updates from the vault back to the client over time.

In the example above, the vault updates are simply logged. You can change this behaviour as required (e.g. to call an API whenever an update is produced).

Comment: would you say that this same approach applies with Corda 4?

Comment: yes, in corda 4 also this is the way to react to any change on corda ledger